# kSystemSoundID_Vibrate not working with AVAudioPlayer Play

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, playback, vibration

I am working on a half-duplex VOIP call app. In that I am trying to play tones along-with vibration during floor exchanges - floor exchanges are done to change the talker from A to B or vice-versa for a half-duplex call. If I try to play tones using AudioServicesPlayAlertSound, then it plays sound when user gets the call, but not during floor exchanges, due to possible mixing issues with call audio. So I replaced AudioServicesPlayAlertSound with AVAudioPlayer's play function. So, now I am able to play the tones perfectly during the call, i.e. during the floor exchanges, i.e. it mixes well with the VOIP call audio. However if I try to add vibrate functionality using AudioServicesPlayAlertSound, it does not vibrate the device, the function gets called but it doesn't take into effect. If I comment out AVAudioPlayer's function to play the tone, then the vibrate function works. Can somebody please suggest what I am missing ?

SNIPPET:

```
NSLog(@"Play toneIncoming");
[_audioPlayerIncoming setDelegate:self];
[_audioPlayerIncoming play];
NSLog(@"vibrate now");
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
//OR AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

I tried above 2 functions for vibrate, but they work only if I comment out AVAudioPlayer's play function, but I need to play a specific tone for different events for VOIP call, so I need that functionality too.

Comment: Did you find answer? I'm looking to vibrate the device as soon as user starts recording audio i.e. after this [AVAudioRecorder record];

Comment: It is not possible as per apple doc. Quoting them here "the device does not vibrate if your app’s audio session is configured with the AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord or AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord audio session category." Check out https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesPlayAlertSound

Comment: Please refer the following link, it may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111877/can-i-play-a-sound-with-vibrate-using-avaudioplayer