# Can I play a sound with vibrate using AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I have AVAudioPlayer playing a sound for a message alert during chat, I also want the phone to vibrate. Is it possible to do this in AVAudioPlayer or do I need to use a different method?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To play a sound:

```
NSString *source = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"beep" ofType:@"mp3"];
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:source] error:nil];
self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;
self.audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
self.audioPlayer.volume = 1.0; 
[self.audioPlayer play];
```

Swift 2.2 version:

```
var source = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("beep", ofType: "mp3")!
do {
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL.fileURLWithPath(source))
}
catch let error {
    // error handling
}
audioPlayer.delegate = self
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0
audioPlayer.volume = 1.0
audioPlayer.play()
```

Swift 3.0 version:

```
var source = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "beep", ofType: "mp3")!
do {
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: source))
}
catch {
    // error handling
}
audioPlayer.delegate = self
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0
audioPlayer.volume = 1.0
audioPlayer.play()
```

To vibrate:

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

Vibration is in `Audiotoolbox.framework` and playing a sound is in `AVFoundation.framework`.

Please note that some devices (iPod Touch) cannot vibrate and this won't simply work.

Comment: @Kex My pleasure. :) If you have any troubles please let me know. If this answer is working for you please accept this answer.

Comment: sorry was just about to, had to wait ten minutes! thanks

Comment: It's 2015, properties auto synthesize now. You should use self.audioPlayer as the compiler does the rest for us now

Comment: this is not working for me. I'm trying to loop a vibration to have it during the sound. If I try to vibrate after the sound it doesn't work.