# Objective-C: vibration does not works

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos

so I am writing payload for jailbroken iOS and it should give you an ability to vibrate through MobileTerminal:

```
-(void)vibrate {
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
}
```

But after I am running my CLI executable trying to vibrate my device I got no vibration.

I have jailbroken iPhone with iOS 13.2.2

For build I am using Theo with all Frameworks needed for my app.

I really can’t understand what I am doing wrong.

**NOTE:** Vibration turned on in Settings.

**P.S:** This project placed here:  https://github.com/enty8080/ac1d

Create Pull Request if you want :)

Comment: I think this may not be possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055344/ksystemsoundid-vibrate-not-working-with-avaudioplayer-play . Had similar problem long ago when trying to generate keyboard clicks and eventually did it the hard way using a prerecorded sound file.

Answer (score 0):

For vibration, you need

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h> 

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (1352);
```

But in your case, the issue may depend.
Maybe you're missing the correct entitlements, maybe the device's vibration motor is dead, maybe vibrations are turned off in settings and you may not be aware (in accessibility).

The best way would be to add the line above in an empty Xcode project and see if it reacts. If it does work from Xcode, but not from Theos, you may be missing some headers, or entitlements from your CLI.